# Redshift throwing Invalid Digit error only when a second WHERE condition is added

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, pyodbc

I'm using Python to query a Redshift server that has improperly formatted numbers. I am able to filter out non-numbers and query based on the column's numeric value like so:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect(...)

q = '''
select *
from
(
    select 
    cast(oldcol as numeric) as newcol
    from tablename
    where oldcol similar to '[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?' 
)
where newcol > 10
'''
pd.read_sql(q, conn)
```

However, when I change the WHERE statement to:

```
where newcol > 10 and newcol < 150
```

or

```
where newcol between 10 and 150
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Invalid digit, Value '-', Pos 2, Type: Decimal \nDETAIL:  \n  -----------------------------------------------\n  error:  Invalid digit, Value '-', Pos 2, Type: Decimal \n  code:      1207\n  context:   85-59\n  query:     82218981\n  location:  :0\n  process:   query1_125_82218981 [pid=0]\n  -----------------------------------------------\n\n (30) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

But there shouldn't be any rows where there is a '-' in newcol, because otherwise the first query wouldn't have worked, and no rows return if I change the WHERE statement to

```
where newcol similar to '%-%'
```

I'm getting the same error if I use another numeric column, convert to decimal instead of numeric, reverse the order of the comparisons, use different comparison values, and execute the code using cursor = conn.cursor() cursor.execute(q).

Comment: Interesting.  It is possible that the query optimizer is doing something wrong but there may be other subtleties at play.  Can you post sample data that recreates this issue?

Comment: Wish I could but I can't, legally speaking I can't share any of this data

Answer (score 0):

If this is the optimizer advancing a where condition inappropriately you could try applying a redundant where clause to suss this out.  Say ...

```
where newcol > 10 and newcol < 150 and newcol::text similar to '[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?'
```

This is just a guess as to what might help "unbreak" the issue.  You may need to play with this to convince the optimizer to do the right thing.

This said I suspect it is much more likely that the issue is in the data.  The report of '-' is likely just Redshift not knowing what should be reported as the data and not actually some part of the data.  My best guess as to a likely cause is that the data being fed to CAST() does not fit in a default numeric data type which is numeric(18,0).  If your string data values break this type definition I can see this error message occurring.

The reason you may not be seeing the error in the original query is that it produces a lot of output that is buffered (or LIMITed) and the query produces results before it gets to the problem value.  Try sending the output of the original query (without a TOP or LIMIT) to a temp table and see if it completes without error as a test.  You could also just remove the where clause and see if all of the inner query's data is processable.

This is just a guess and there are likely other ways that the problem you are seeing is a data expectation issue and not a RS bug.  I have seen RS bugs in the past (often with the optimizer) so I'll never rule this possibility out.

================

After some back and forth in the comments it looks like Redshift may be advancing a WHERE clause inappropriately.  Here's how that could work.

Redshift gains a huge performance boost by applying WHERE clauses against table metadata.  The optimizer will almost certainly flatten this set of 2 SELECTs to gain performance.  It may try to take the outer WHERE clause - "where newcol > 10 and newcol < 150" - and apply it to the source data table's metadata.  Reducing the rows read from disk could be a great help.  It would do this by (effectively) changing the WHERE to - "where cast(oldcol as numeric) > 10 and cast(oldcol as numeric) < 150".  Perfectly valid, right?  But no, this cast is only being applied to some rows of the inner query, not all.

So how do you fix it / prove it?

Your query structure is basically a CASE statement but using a WHERE clause to do it. Your WHERE clause is "changing" how the data should be processed.  The Redshift optimizer isn't likely thinking this way and getting crossed up (if this theory holds).  If we add the data processing information into the data processing part of the query then this should help Redshift see that it cannot flatten the queries the way it wants to.

Here's the experiment I'd try:

```
select *
from
(
    select 
    decode(oldcol similar to '[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?', true, cast(oldcol as numeric)) as newcol
    from tablename
    where oldcol similar to '[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?' 
)
where newcol > 10 and newcol < 150
```

(decode() is just a shortened/simpler CASE syntax)

Now the optimizer will need to bring the decode() into the flattened WHERE clause and "protect" the query from the data error.  This structure will make the inner WHERE clause unneeded but let's not change too many things at once.

IF THIS WORKS then we likely have a good handle on what is going on.  There's no guarantee that this theory is correct in this case as changing the query have just "moved" the issue but it would be "likely correct".  This info will also help in creating a simple test case to submit to AWS.

Comment: Turns out I'm able to get it to work if I have the subquery select the top 1 million rows, even though there are only 300K rows in the entire table. And while I don't have permissions to create a temp table, if I examine the data in Python, there aren't any numbers that are too large.

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug after all, I really can't find anything wrong with the data once that initial filter is applied

Comment: it is possible but a few things to try.  can you add an ORDER BY clause to ensure that the entire set of data needs to be read before any output is produced.  Do this for the working query and the failing query.

Comment: Adding an ORDER BY doesn't make a difference - the working query still works, and the failing query still fails

Comment: Smelling more and more like an optimizer bug.  Let me propose an experiment in the answer ...

Comment: Wow you were right, that worked! Very impressive. Sounds like the best option is to use your suggested syntax for queries going forward and see if I can get the vendor I'm working with to open a case with AWS

Comment: Yes, I'd open a case but thinking about it I'm not sure AWS will see this as a bug. This is a hazard in the data / query and I'm not sure there's any guarantee of order of operation based on level of query.  It will be interesting to see how they react.  It's almost as if you wrote 3 where clauses and expected the first to run first so the that the others wouldn't error (almost).  Very curious to see what they say.

Comment: As for syntax - just avoid using where clauses to prevent invalid data operations.  Use CASE or decode() instead.